# Is it possible to have all content types as dropdown field in one content type in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, nodes

I have one requirement, where I need to create one content type having field 'Type' and it should have Dropdown list of content type present in that Drupal project.
Is it possible to do it? Can anybody suggest me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can suggest four different solutions:

1. Using [Bundle Name Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/bundle_name_reference) module , of course I haven't used this module and I'm not sure if it presents the same functionality as you desire.
2. Easy but not always working , Create a taxonomy vocabulary and add terms having same name as your content type does , then you can add a taxonomy reference to your content type targeting that vocab.
3. The problem in solution 2 is that when a new content type is added you manually must add a term for that in your vocab , to overcome that problem you can write a simple module then implement [hook_node_type_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_type_insert/7.x) and there you can add term to your targeting vocab programmatically so you wont need to manually add new terms any more.
4. The last and the most complicated solution , maybe you can write it as a module so others can use it in future. You will need to write a module to implement a new [field type](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/group/field/7.x) , you will need to implement hook_field_schema to add new table for your field type (there you can store bundle ID of selected content type) , a field widget which must be Select type and its options can be filled using this function : [node_type_get_types](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_type_get_types/7.x).